# Clean water turbidity sensor

Tags: microcontroller, adc, phototransistor, photoresistor

I'm working on a project to determine the water clarity, using a MCU with a turbidity sensor. I have tested sensors such as: [Cheap Dishwasher sensor](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/18/AAS-920-479B-Thermometrics-TSW-10-052214-web-850660.pdf), and while it works for changes in turbidity in dirty water, it isn't great with clean water.

For example, the water I am testing in the ocean could have enough clarity to see down 20ft. The value returned on the sensor is about the same as if the clarity is 50ft, or 60ft. It is able to easily determine the difference between 2ft and 10ft, when there is a huge difference in suspended particles.

I am using an Atmega ADC with a 10bit resolution. I know I would be better off with an external ADC, and making my own sensor with a photoresistor/transistor and IR emitter. My question is, is there anything I can do with the sensor design to force the curve to be affected more in the clean water side that the dirty? If not, is my best bet to just ensure I have a high resolution ADC with very little noise?

Thank you very much

Comment: There's no datasheet on the Amazon link. What else have you got? Put the info in the question (rather than in the comments.) We need graphs, specs, etc. Compare the mode of operation and output specs with a high quality device.

Comment: @Transistor My bad, I don't know why I posted that Amazon link. New link in question

Comment: The Amphenol PDF has an illegible graph in it. Looking at the layout of the LED and photo-transistor I'd say your only bet with that type of sensor would be to increase distance from the LED to the transistor. This, of course means that stray light is likely to become a problem. Just a though, but industrial photo-sensors pulse the light to get the difference between background light and reflected or transmitted light (depending on sensor type).

Comment: @Transistor updated the link

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an optical rather than electrical design problem. However, you might consider instead of measuring path loss, transmitting light in one direction and measuring reflection off particles in another. Think about what car headlights do when operating in even slight fog conditions - you can still see fine, but you start to get lots of nuisance reflection, so measure that.  If you can't get perfect shielding from other light sources, use a lock-in amplifier.

Comment: You get what you pay for. For a cheap dishwasher sensor, 20ft and 50ft clarity is essentially "clean enough", that's why there's no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you are limited in resolution by the distance through the water sample with your current sensor. The datasheet shows you have no more than 5.7 mm of water depth providing resolvable transmissive information.
 You are also severely limited with the sensor since it provides only transmissive sensing without any backscatter sensing.
Perhaps you could make you own sensor from two flat glass plates and install multiple mirrors to bend the sensing path through multiple passes through the water. This would give a longer path but still lacks any backscatter sensing.

[This](http://www.fondriest.com/environmental-measurements/equipment/measuring-water-quality/turbidity-sensors-meters-and-methods/#TurbidMM1) may be of help ...have a look at the GLI Method 2 sensor.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.. The thought I had for the sensor I would make would have the emitter shine down a tube with the detector either directly down it, or up at a 90 degree angle from it. Just to give it a longer distance to shine through

Answer (score 1):

If the water samples result in some mid band output from the sensor, then increasing the sensitivity of the measurement within that portion of the curve may help.

In practice this means amplifying that region of the curve and injecting an offset to bring the ouput back into range of your ADC. This will also amplify any noise in that region so you may need to include a digital filter in your algorithm.

In practice you take an intial range reading of your sensor without amplification. You then output this value to a DAC as the offset voltage. Then you bring in line a gain amplifier. The amplifier could have programmable gain if the variation in sampled turbidity warrants it.  This technique effectively performs a digital zoom on that part of the sensor output curve.

Answer (score 1):

Dishwasher sensors measure the attenuation of light due to particles present in the water. If the water is clear enough, there will be hardly any particles between the hubs of the sensor, so it will be unable to tell the difference between clean water and very clean water. Even if you amplify the signal (increasing effective ADC resolution), you will mostly read noise.

You can try to make several measurements and sum up the results. This will increase the chances that an eventual particle will show up and be registered, at the expense of longer measurement time.

The ideal solution would be to acquire a [nephelometric sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephelometer) which measures the light reflected by the particles rather than attenuation. These are great for low-NTU measurements, but they typically must be submerged in a large quantity of water to work, so you can't use them if you collect water samples.